# Allow a user to use my Microsoft account only to login to computer and not to access my online account data

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have Windows 10 computer linked with my personal Hotmail account. I want to give the computer to someone else.
There is some software which I cannot get to run as another user (old legacy programs).

Is there a way I can give them my computer, so they still login to the computer as me, but it is totally localized, and it cannot access my Hotmail and Onedrive accounts? 
Basically as me, but offline (while still being connected to the internet).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For hotmail, all you have to do is logout off your account and ensure that the
browser hasn't saved your password.

For hiding one disk, you can for a naive user just remove in Disk Management
the drive-letter, later on returning it when you get back the computer.

A more heavy-weight solution would be to encrypt the disk, or even take it out
physically, but with these solutions there is always a risk of losing the
data with the slightest error.

Comment: Thanks - will that stop the windows 10 mail app from accessing the mail? So would I give the new user the pin, not the password?

Comment: This was for the browser. For any other mail program you will need to save your local emails and then delete the account, later on restoring the account and returning the emails. Saving the locally-stored emails is not required if you are using an IMAP server that remotely hosts *all* your emails.